# Retrofit errorBody strange behaviour

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

If I write:

```
String str = response.errorBody().string();
String errors = Misc.get_errors(str);
```

Everything works fine (`get_errors` being a `final static` method which only reformat `str`).

However if I directly write:

```
String errors = Misc.get_errors(response.errorBody().string());
```

it fails.

My Java being a bit rusty, I am wondering why the result is different.

EDIT:

```
public final static String get_errors(String errors) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {
                JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(errors);

                Iterator<String> it = jObjError.keys();

                while (it.hasNext()) {

                    sb.append(jObjError.get(it.next()).toString().replace("[\"", "").replace("\"]", ""));
                    sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }



        return sb.toString();


Callback<Joueur> callback = new Callback<Joueur>(){

                                                          @Override
                                                          public void onResponse(Call<Joueur> call, Response<Joueur> response){

                                                              // display message if http error(s)
                                                              if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                                                                  try{
                                                                      String raw_errors = response.errorBody().string();
                                                                      String errors = Misc.get_errors(raw_errors);
                                                                      Toast display = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errors, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                                                      display.show();
                                                                  }
                                                                  catch(Exception e){
                                                                      e.printStackTrace();
                                                                  }

                                                              }
                                                              // otherwise, launch new intent
                                                              else{

                                                                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(Inscription_activity.this, Connexion_activity.class);
                                                                  Inscription_activity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

                                                              }


                                                              }
```

Comment: How it fails? Can you please attach your stacktrace?

Comment: What is the error? Compile time?

Comment: In the second case, the String is empty.

Comment: How are you trying it? Are you reading response.errorBody() twice?

Comment: I've added the whole code in the first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consuming the error body (since it is a ResponseBody), it will become empty (because it is a buffer and it is consumed). Thats why it only works for the first time.

If you want to make copies of the response to be used, you can do this.

```
val oldResponseBody = it.response().errorBody()
val responseBytes = oldResponseBody.bytes()
val reponseCopy1 = ResponseBody.create(oldResponseBody.contentType(), responseBytes)
val reponseCopy2 = ResponseBody.create(oldResponseBody.contentType(), responseBytes)
```

Be aware that this method copies all of the bytes of the response into the memory at once.

Comment: Any way to get around this? I need the response body on multiple levels!

Comment: Yes, I modified my answer.

Comment: Yes that works! 
But I need to put the data back in the same object. I'm using RxJava with Retrofit and I handle the error on API level and UI level.

Comment: I think one option would be modifying Retrofit's RxJava adapter and adding another operator to it's chain, and convert the errors to something like `RetainableResponseBody` in which you store the bytes and don't make it empty upon consumption. I did search around and currently there is no way for the `ResponseBody` to retain it's bytestream.

Comment: No problem, Please choose it as accepted one (if it is!).

Answer (score 0):

To get read-only copy of error body (tested on OkHttp3 ver. `4.9.1`):

```
response()?.errorBody()?.source()?.buffer?.snapshot()?.utf8()
```